# How to setup scrollbar for LWC with "extends LightningDatatable"?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, custom, issue

I have implemented a custom datatype for the salesforce lightning-datable component, however, I`m going to add a scrollbar to my datatable, but I cannot achieve this. Looks like the workaround from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) does not work, because during the extenting process, we are having different fдow of insertion datatatable to DOM. Would be very happy if someone could help me with this.

customDatatable.js

```
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';

export default class CustomDatatable extends LightningDatatable {
  

    static customTypes = {
        input: {
            template: input,
            standardCellLayout: true,
            typeAttributes: ['rowKey', 'name', 'type', 'required', 'options'],
        },
    };
   }
```

uiDatatable.html

```
 <div class="slds-p-around_small" style="height:200px">
            <c-custom-datatable
                    columns={columns}
                    data={tableData}
                    hide-checkbox-column="true"
                    key-field={keyField}
                    onrowaction={handleRowClick}
                    resize-column-disabled="true"
            >
            </c-enhanced-datatable>
        </div>
```

UPDATE:
Here is the screen shots of standard component, as far as you can see, header is sticked to the top, and you can scroll the body
[image]

however when you are trying to do the same thing with an extended component I cannot achieve the same behavior, here header is not attached to the top also "loadMore" event are not fired as well.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show the how it looks now and what's your expectation?

Comment: @Gopal thanks for response, I`ve updated my question with few screen shots